# Java Code Can't understand why it give the error?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object, oop

Here I make two classes A And prac2 and I just want to print the method from the both of class . But I got the error type of Class A is already defined . So I can't undestand why the error comes

```
package revision;


public class Prac2 extends A {
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("child");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj1 = new Prac2() ;
        Prac2 obj2 = new Prac2() ;

        obj1.m();
        obj2.m();
        
    }

}

class A {
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("parent") ;
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void revision.A.m()'
    at revision.Prac2.main(Prac2.java:13)
```

```
The type A is already defined
```

Comment: just run your code and everything seem fine with no error, did you miss anything?

Comment: As per error message somewhere ```void revision.A.m()``` is called. Can't see in this code. Please make sure the file you are running and the code you post are the same and complete.

Comment: "The type A is already defined" should give you a hint what is going wrong: You have a class named `A` somewhere else in the package.

Comment: The problem most likely  is not in the code but in how you compile and run it. Can you provide more information about how you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems to be ok with no exception, but it will print:

> child

> child

you extends `Prac2` from `A`, that means `A` is the super class and if you want to get access to both methods, you should create instances from `A`:

```
class Prac2 extends A {
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("child");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj1 = new A() ;
        A obj2 = new Prac2() ;

        obj1.m();
        obj2.m();

    }

}

class A {
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("parent") ;
    }
}
```

the output will be:

> parent

> child